# How to count values in Python when two of the columns are greater than 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

| ID | Month | P1 | P2 | ... | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 2 | 0 | ... | 2 |
| 1 | Feb | 3 | 1 | ... | 0 |
| 1 | Mar | 3 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | Jan | 19 | 1 | ... | 20 |
| 2 | Feb | 8 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | Mar | 12 | 0 | ... | 1 |

I want to create another dataframe that will count monthly IDs where Sales and other column (P1,P2, ...Pn) both are greater than 0

For eg.
In the above dataframe in Jan there were 2 Ids 1 and 2 which had P1>0 and Sales >0
In Feb there are 0 Ids which had P1>0 & Sales>0 (P1 is greater than 0 for both IDs but Sales is 0)
In Mar there is 1 Id 2 which had P1>0 & Sales>0

I want to see result something like this:

| Month | P1 | P2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 2 | 1 | ... |
| Feb | 0 | 0 | ... |
| March | 1 | 0 | ... |

I was thinking of creating a dataframe for P1,P2,... Pn using a for loop that counts a number of instances. But this will be a time-consuming process.

Can you please suggest me an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom aggregation with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (df.filter(like='P').where(df['Sales'].gt(0)).gt(0)
         .groupby(df['Month'], sort=False).sum()
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Or from an explicit list of columns:

```
cols = ['P1', 'P2']
out = (df[cols].where(df['Sales'].gt(0)).gt(0)
         .groupby(df['Month'], sort=False).sum()
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
  Month  P1  P2
0   Jan   2   1
1   Feb   0   0
2   Mar   1   0
```

Comment: Sorry @mozway. I want to count instances where (P1&Sales), (P2&Sales),....(Pn&Sales) are greater than 0
I think the above code will only return counts where each of the column is >0.. not the combination

Comment: @Mufeez sorry, see the update

Answer (score 0):

```
def fct(d):
    return d.groupby("ID")[["P1", "P2"]].agg(lambda x: ((x > 0) & (d["Sales"] > 0)).any()).apply(sum)

result = d.groupby("Month").apply(fct)
```

Comment: Please add a code description and not just only code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to specify/denote the conditions explicitly:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Month': df.Month, 'P1': df.P1 * df.Sales > 0, 'P2': df.P2 * df.Sales > 0})\
 .groupby('Month', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

---

```
  Month  P1  P2
0  Jan    2   1
1  Feb    0   0
2  Mar    1   0
```